# Is ΔH = ΔU + ΔPV only valid for gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

[image: Question in doubt]

In this question, formula **ΔH = ΔU + ΔPV** is used. In the solution, **ΔPV** is replaced for **RTΔng**. As there are solid products also in this equation, don't we consider ΔPV for them. Also if there were liquid products will we consider it's ΔPV?

Comment: We usually consider the volume of pure solids and liquids to be constant while solving such problems.

Comment: We *often*, even *usually*, consider the volume constant. But not always - e.g. for some phase changes in solids the volume change can be quite significant.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is best not used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of essential parts.

Answer (score 3):

$\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta (pV)$ is always valid, as it is the alternative way of the definition $H = U + pV$.

But $\Delta (pV) = RT\Delta n_g$ is at constant T exactly valid only for reactions of ideal gases.

For real gases, regardless  of if all or just some components are gaseous, it is valid approximately. Contribution of condensed phases is then neglected.

If a reaction has no gaseous component, or if there is no change in total amount of gas, the approximation $\Delta (pV) \approx RT\Delta n_g$ is not applicable. OTOH, the term $\Delta (pV)$ is often negligible. But at specific cases like involving thermal dilation and compressibilty of condensed phases at constant volume, the $\Delta (pV)$ term can be very significant.